# Scaling an object in three.js

Tags: three.js, scaling

I am getting 
Matrix3.getInverse(): can't invert matrix, determinant is 0        three.js 3976
error when I am trying to scale a cube object.

```
var object = new.THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
 xScale = 0.1;
 object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = xScale;
```

Could someone help me out of this.

Comment: `object.scale.set(xScale, xScale, xScale)`

Comment: Uhura meant object.scale.set(xScale, yScale, zScale)

Comment: @uhura Why is that required? `object.scale` is a `Vector3` so it ought to be modified exactly in the same way as (e.g.) `object.position`...   In fact using `set` doesn't solve anything (just tried).

Comment: anyone solved this? :'(

Answer (score 17):

`Matrix3.getInverse(): can't invert matrix, determinant is 0` usually happens when either the `scale.x`, `scale.y` or `scale.z` are 0. Make sure you're not scaling the object to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be trying to use a `Matrix3` where a `Matrix4` is required. At least in r61 of the three.js library, the line you refer to is pulling from the matrix array beyond index 8 (ie. a 16 element matrix vs. a 9 element). 
If you need any advice beyond that provide some code and description to what your trying to achieve with the inverse matrix, good luck!